# How to cache a ActiveRecord model object which contains carrierwave uploader to Redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I have a user model which has a carrierwave uploader for storing ths users profile picture

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :profilepic, LogoUploaderUploader
```

I want to cache this User object in redis. While caching I call the to_json method on the activerecord object which converts the profilepic field in the user object to a hash containing the url of the image

```
user={id:1, username: "sam", profilepic: {url:"path_to_image.jpg"}}
```

This part is fine and I can store it in redis. But the trouble comes when I retrieve the data from redis and try to convert it to a ActiveRecord object like the following

```
user=User.new(json_data)
```

The profilepic field comes null. Looks like it is not able to deserialize the profilepic hash `profilepic: {url:"path_to_image.jpg"}`to a proper value.

Is there anyway I can get back the proper value for profilepic after saving to redis.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing an `ActiveRecord::Base` in Redis, you should just store its `id` and reload the object from the database when needed.

The reason is pretty simple: It is not possible to regenerate an instance of `ActiveRecord::Base` by serializing it to JSON and restoring it with `Model.new(json_data)`. Because `to_json` might not serialize all attributes and `Model.new` might not restore the instances internal state.

In your example, the specific problem is that `User.new` expects a file object for the `profilepic`. But `to_json` method is not able to render a file object into the JSON, instead, it renders a hash containing a URL.

Comment: I was trying to introduce a caching layer by saving the records in  Redis. Loading from db would  defeat the purpose. If there is a way to assign a url back to a carrierwave uploader field, thats what I am looking for....

Comment: Is your Database for a simple query like that slower than Redis? Why? Indexes missing?

Comment: This was mostly so that I could benchmark  for myself how "blazingly fast" redis is than mysql especially with different kinds of where clauses on the User model.

Comment: Temporarily I did it with the following  workaround.
I added the following in User model
attr_accessor :picture
and while creating User object from json, I just read from user[:profilepic][:url] and assign to picture

Then I read from picture in the views...